# Can this be solved with Ehcache?

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I would like to use Ehcache for the following task:

There's a routine that can be executed only *n* times a day. Each time it's invoked, a counter in the database is decreased. When it reaches 0, this fact is denoted in a shared hash map (filed under the current date), and there's no need to contact the database until the end of day. The database counter is reset to *n* at midnight by an asynchronous task, the hash map does not have appropriate entry for the new date, and database polling resumes.

Now I'd like to implement this behaviour in Ehcache, because we use it already for other caches, and because I'd like to be able to turn off all caching in one place. This poses the following problems:

1. The condition for cache activation is known only inside the `@Cacheable` method (when it's discovered that the DB counter is zero). This probably rules out declarative cache specification, correct?
2. The time to live needs to be specified as a point in time, not as duration. Is this possible?

Comment: To me it would be less error-prone to use the date in the key of the cache so that the moment a new day dawns, code will start to look for the information under the new key. When the old key still exists, older jobs of the previous day will then still look in the old key and notice "Oh, I don't need to do anything" even though newer jobs will. I'm just thinking out loud here not knowing the inner details of the code that will be using this system. Perhaps what I'm saying here is utterly useless to your system design.

Comment: @Mada what you want to cache .. ? shared hash map to hold completed date and 0 ? or to avoid the DB hit from N-0 when ever the routine invoked ?. Db would hold only one day of data ? what will happen to HashMap jvm shutdonw ?

Comment: @Mani Basically, I want to cache a string (key) and the counter value from the moment it reaches 0 till midnight. So the cache will only be used AFTER the counter becomes 0 and BEFORE midnight.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to implements eviction policy if you want to do that with ehcache.

see here : http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/cache-eviction-algorithms#plugging-in-your-own-eviction-algorithm